# How to pass the values of a connection to a subscription?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to return a subscription which consists of the following:

```
const postsSubscription = gql`
  subscription postAdded {
    postAdded {
      id
      title
      description
      author{
        name
      }
    }
  }
`
```

What happens is that Author is type of User, and I just pass an authorId. That means that I don't have the author name when I create the Post:

```
    createPost: async (root, req, { posts }) => {
      const Item = {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        authorId: '565dbdc0-36f2-4bba-be67-c126d0c71fff',
        ...req
      }
      await posts.create({ Item })

      pubsub.publish('postAdded', { postAdded: Item })

      return Item
    },
```

Here is the Author resolver:

```
Post: {
    author: async({ authorId }, req, { users }) => {
      const Key = { id: authorId }
      const { Item } = await users.get({ Key })

      return Item
    }
  }
```

Here is the schema:

```
type Post {
  id: ID
  title: String
  description: String
  author: User @relation(name: "PostAuthor")
}

type User {
  id: ID
  name: String
  email: String
  password: String
  posts: [Post] @relation(name: "UserPosts")
}

type PostPayload {
  post: Post
}

type CreateUserPayload {
  user: User
}

type Query {
  allPosts: [Post]
  allUsers: [User]
  post(id: ID!): Post
  user(id: ID!): User
}

type Mutation {
  createPost(input: CreatePostInput!): PostPayload
  updatePost(input : UpdatePostInput!): PostPayload
  createUser(input : CreateUserInput!): CreateUserPayload
}

type Subscription {
  postAdded: Post
}

input CreatePostInput {
  title: String!
  description: String!
}


input UpdatePostInput {
  id: ID!
  title: String!,
  description: String!
}

input CreateUserInput {
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription: Subscription
}
```

So, my question is, how to pass all required fields (including the connections) to the subscription?

Comment: Is this field resolver being called?  can you create a reproduction or share the schema as well?

Comment: There you go @Urigo It's working because when I query the `allPosts` or `post` I get the author back. But I cant get this information back on the subscription. So it breaks, saying that it needs the `author`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, but not as I wanted.
1) I had to remove this part of the code:

```
Post: {
  author: async({ authorId }, req, { users }) => {
    const Key = { id: authorId }
    const { Item } = await users.get({ Key })

    return Item
  }
}
```

and added this function to the createPost function itself:

```
createPost: async (root, { input }, { posts, users }) => {
  const Key = { id: '3b1884b8-9ee7-4d9d-ab2f-ff32bcd69b9a' }
  const user = await users.get({ Key })

  const Item = {
    id: uuid.v4(),
    author: user.Item,
    ...input
  }
  await posts.create({ Item })
  await pubsub.publish(POST_ADDED_TOPIC, { [POST_ADDED_TOPIC]: Item })

  return { post: Item }
}
```

So this is kinda fixed. But, if you know how to fix this, using the first approach (Post: author thingy) I'll appreciate.